# Install component conditionally in Wix

Tags: wix, custom-component

We have a Wix project for our Installer. Is it possible to check if a file exists?
Basically, for some of our config files, we want to pass in the path of the file that is actually not present in our installer script but pass in the path of the file to a public property on command line.
In this case we want the config file component to use this passed in config file during the installation instead of the default config file.

Is this possible?

I have tried something like this:

```
<?if FileExist([PORTALCONFIGPATH])?>
      <File Id='webConfig' Name='web.config' DiskId='1' Source='[PORTALCONFIGPATH]' KeyPath='yes'/>
<?else?>
      <File Id='webConfig' Name='web.config' DiskId='1' Source='web.config' KeyPath='yes'/>             
<?endif?>
```

Someway to check that the passed in file name exists then install the passed in file otherwise use the default file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WiX [FileSearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/filesearch.html), [DirectorySearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/directorysearch.html), [Condition](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html), and [CopyFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/copyfile.html) elements are what you are looking to use. Create a property, when executing the msi if the property is set then the DirectorySearch and FileSearch elements will look in the path for that property, setting another property (MYFILEEXISTS for example) then if MYFILEEXISTS CopyFile will run with the path.

Comment: Thanks Rick, how can I make sure that my file search actions are run before it tries to install the component for the web.config file?

Comment: Searches execute before files are copied, unfortunately I can't seem to find official documentation stating that, I did find this which seems to say that in a round about way http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/10/from-msi-to-wix-part-3.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and post here.